# PlotLegends on DensityPlot

Tags: plotting, legending, visualization

I have plot

```
 DensityPlot[100*Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotLegends -> {Automatic}]
```

I wanna see the PlotLegend only in range 0 to 10. How do it?

Comment: do you get what you need using `PlotLegends  -> BarLegend[{Automatic,  {0, 10}}]`?

Comment: .. or using `PlotLegends ->BarLegend[{Blend["M10DefaultDensityGradient", Rescale[#, {0,100}]]&, {0,10}}]`?